# Google Sheet - apps script create a problem if i paste few fields together

Tags: google-apps-script

The following script is trying to format column A with my specific date format (dd/MM/yyyy):

```
const FIRST_ROW = 2; // Header row is protected conventionally
const cols = {
  "date": 1 // column number that contains date
}

/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  var id, ss;

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  let col = range.getColumn();
  
  if (col == cols.date && range.getRow() >= FIRST_ROW) {       
    let value = range.getValue();
    if(value != ""){
      let newDate = new Date(value);
      let timeCheck = newDate.getTime();
      let isTime = (timeCheck === timeCheck);
      if (!isTime) {
        let message = "'" + value + "' is not a date. Please enter a valid date.";
        let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.alert(message);
        range.setValue(""); 
      } else {
        range.setValue(newDate).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

It is working well if I paste the date value from another cell.
but, if I copy a few fields (e.g. column A-D from row 3) and paste them into an empty row (e.g. column A-D row 3) then column B-D gets the same date value as column A.
see an example on this print screen.
[image]

I need to make sure only Column A changed his format, and all other columns remain as is.
Please help.

Comment: A e.range can be a group of selected cells.  You probable need to check the range before setValue();  In your case setValue() takes the value of A and copies it to the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `e.range` will contain the entire range that was edited, so if it was more than one cell and you later call `setValue()` on it, then the value will be applied to the entire range.

A quick fix could be to just make sure to always choose the first row and column within the range using [`getCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column). So instead of this:

```js
range.setValue(""); // sets value to the whole range
```

Try this:

```js
range.getCell(1,1).setValue(""); // sets value only to the first cell in the range
```

Note that this will only work if you're pasting a single row. If you want to also cover pasting multiple rows you will need to iterate through all the rows.

**Edit:** As requested here's a sample of how to iterate through the rows. Showing an alert message for each invalid date would probably be very disruptive or not work at all so I changed the logic a bit to just show a single message at the end informing the user that some fields were not dates. Your preferred approach may be different but you can take this as a sample on how to do the iteration.

```js
const FIRST_ROW = 2; // Header row is protected conventionally
const cols = {
  "date": 1 // column number that contains date
}

/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn();

  if (col == cols.date && range.getRow() >= FIRST_ROW) {
    let values = range.getValues(); //get the full range of values, this is an array
    let success = true; //this will change if at least one of the rows is not a date

    values.forEach(function (value, index) {
      //each value variable is a one dimensional array for each row
      //the array length is whatever number of columns it has
      //since we only want the first column we only need value[0]
      if (value[0] != "") {
        //I'm using a different way to parse dates
        //Date.parse() will return unix time if it's a valid date or NaN if it isn't
        //so we can use isNaN() to validate this
        if (isNaN(Date.parse(value[0]))) {
          //getCell() starts at 1 unlike regular arrays so we add the index var to it
          //which should start at 0
          range.getCell(index + 1, 1).setValue("");
          success = false;
        } else {
          let newDate = new Date(value[0]);
          range.getCell(index + 1, 1).setValue(newDate).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
      }
    })

    if(!success){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("One or more values in the date column were not valid and have been deleted")
    }
  }
}
```

The main difference is that you need to use [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get an array of the values in the range.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it solve my problem. And you are right that it is still not perfect in case I paste more than 1 row with wrong format. on such case only the first row get fixed by the script and set my requested format. How should I iterate to handle such rare scenario that can happen?

Comment: I added a sample that you can take as a guide to iterate through the first row even if multiple values are pasted.